# Finding incompatible Objective-C category definitions from compiler warning after Swift 3 migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

After migrating to Swift 3 compiler gives me a warning:

> Some object files have incompatible Objective-C category definitions.
>   Some category metadata may be lost. All files containing Objective-C
>   categories should be built using the same compiler.

Does anyone know how can I find objects or files defined as ***some object files*** from the warning?
I have zillions of extensions and going through all of them would be a madness. Is there an easier way?

I know there are similar questions but no one asks how to find the files/objects responsible for the warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the warning, you will see the area in the build log where probably some library will be named.